# How to get value from website javascript?

Tags: javascript, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

On the webpage I have this:

```
<table class="infobox"><tr>
<td>
<table class="infobox-inner-table">
<tr class="infobox-heading">
<th id="infobox-quick-facts">Quick Facts</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<div class="infobox-spacer"></div>
<div id="infobox-contents-0"></div>
<script>
      WH.markup.printHtml("[ul][li]Requires level 20[\/li][li]Loremaster: Yes[\/li][li]Side: [span class=icon-alliance]Alliance[\/span][\/li][li][icon name=quest_start]Start: [url=\/npc=41129\/surveyor-thurdan]Surveyor Thurdan[\/url][\/icon][\/li][li][icon name=quest_end]End: [url=\/npc=41129\/surveyor-thurdan]Surveyor Thurdan[\/url][\/icon][\/li][li]Sharable[\/li][li]Added in patch 4.0.3.13277[\/li][\/ul]", "infobox-contents-0", {
                allow: WH.markup.CLASS.STAFF,
                dbPage: true,            });
        </script>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Inside the javascript is "Added in patch 4.0.3.13277" and via VBA I have to get the patch number.

Best would be to use getelementsbyclassname("infobox") so it will only look to this , however then I don't know what to do next, .innerText or anything similar to dig up the patch number doesn't apply here.

Comment: Did any of these solutions work for you?

Comment: Hello QHarr, in this case i used solution from MITHU as its easier to understand, seems clearer a possibly faster as it just reads, fits well in how and where i need to use better. However for all my other questions in project I used your solutions only as they are very simple, not complicated and works excelent

Comment: Sure thing :-) Just remember to consider accepting their answer. The solution by @Mithu is nice and concise. Use whatever works for your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can regex out the appropriate script contents then replace the `\/` with `/` ; replace `[` with `<` ; replace `]` with  `>` ; then parse with html parser and grab last `li` element.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTextFromScriptTag()
    'required references Microsoft HTML Object Library; Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions

    'your code

    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    'Set html = htmlsourceobject(e.g.ie.document) ''< this line you need to add in html source object from your prior code
    Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    re.Pattern = "WH\.markup\.printHtml\(""(.*?)"","

    html.body.innerHTML = "<body>" & Replace$(Replace$(Replace$(re.Execute(html.body.innerHTML)(0).SubMatches(0), "[", "<"), "]", ">"), "\/", "/") & "<\body>"

    Dim liNodes As Object

    Set liNodes = html.querySelectorAll("li")
    Debug.Print liNodes.item(liNodes.Length - 1).innerText

End Sub
```

---

Regex:

[image]

Comment: Isn't using such a pattern enough to get the results without replacing with HTML `\[li\](.+?)\[`?

Comment: Over time that pattern IMO may vary be more variable to change. I thought it better to grab the entire section destined to be parsed as html as possibly more stable. I am making the assumption of location rather than of string. If I were certain of the preceeding text e.g. Added patch, then I would probably use regex like @Mithu but locate the appropriate node first using the id before the script and the script tag to locate node.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you directly look around the script to dig out the patch number? This is how I meant:

```
Sub FetchPatchNumber()
    Const Url$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61192812/vba-how-to-getvalue-from-website-javascript"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, patchnum As Object, S$

    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "Added in patch\s*(.*?)\["
        Set patchnum = .Execute(S)
        If patchnum.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox patchnum.item(0).SubMatches(0)
         End If
    End With
End Sub
```